# Why are these two definitions of symplectic structure equivalent?

Tags: differential-geometry

On page 9,10 of http://www.crm.cat/en/Activities/Curs_2018-2019/Documents/barcelona_schlenk.pdf are two definitions of *symplectic structure*.

> [image: Definition 1]
>
> [image: Definition 2]

[Explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7Qao.png)

I am struggling to understand their explanation for why these two definitions are equivalent. Firstly, I lack the motivation for what they do.

1. Why do they take the integral of $\omega_0$?
2. Is $D$ just a disk in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$? Or are we in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ and it is embedded on some plane?
3. What is the meaning of this projection map $\prod_{i}: \mathbb{C}^{n} \to \mathbb{C}(z_i)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer your questions in reverse order.

3) We can think of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}= \mathbb{C}^n$ as being $n$ copies of $\mathbb{R}^2= \mathbb{C}$ so there are natural projection maps

\begin{align} 
&\Pi_i:\,  \mathbb{C}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}\\
&(z_1,...,z_n) \mapsto z_i
\end{align}
The interpretation of which is simply the projection onto the $i$th plane.

2) D is some oriented region in $\mathbb{C}^n= \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ such that $\partial D = \gamma$.

1) On a 2 dimensional space the symplectic form can be though of as the element of area, and thus integrating it along some (oriented) region gives the area of the region. What they have done in (2.1) is integrating $\omega_0$ over $D$, and used Darboux's theorem to write the symplectic form in canonical coordinates. The fact that the area derived in (2.1) is invariant under symplectomorphisms follows directly from that the pullback of the symplectic form by a symplectomorphism is the symplectic form.

Hope this helps.